# How to initialize a nested struct?

Tags: go

I cannot figure out how to initialize a nested struct. Find an example here:
http://play.golang.org/p/NL6VXdHrjh

```
package main

type Configuration struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}

func main() {

    c := &Configuration{
        Val: "test",
        Proxy: {
            Address: "addr",
            Port:    "80",
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just learning go and had exactly the same question. You can omit element types for arrays and maps but not for nested structs. Illogical and inconvenient. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 261, accepted):

Well, any specific reason to not make Proxy its own struct?

Anyway you have 2 options:

The proper way, simply move proxy to its own struct, for example:

```
type Configuration struct {
    Val string
    Proxy Proxy
}

type Proxy struct {
    Address string
    Port    string
}

func main() {

    c := &Configuration{
        Val: "test",
        Proxy: Proxy{
            Address: "addr",
            Port:    "port",
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(c)
    fmt.Println(c.Proxy.Address)
}
```

The less proper and ugly way but still works:

```
c := &Configuration{
    Val: "test",
    Proxy: struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }{
        Address: "addr",
        Port:    "80",
    },
}
```

Comment: In the second method, can we avoid the repetitive struct definition?

Comment: @GauravOjha not all the way, but something like https://play.golang.org/p/n24BD3NlIR

Comment: I think using an embedded type is more apt for is-a relationship.

Comment: as pointed out below by @sepehr you can access the variables directly using the dot notation.

Comment: What if the proxy has a field with struct as type? How to initialize them inside another nested struct?

Comment: @GauravOjha I think I found the more improper way to do it without defining any type.
https://play.golang.org/p/_mHcB0pBtep

Comment: The first proposal leads to name space collisions. Instead of "Proxy" you have to use "ConfigurationProxy" to avoid collisions. And if you do it correctly, you will notice that this gets more annoying with every nesting level.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, it just suggests another course of action. While that's valuable for learning *a* way to achieve this effect (mitigating the XY problem), it would be great if this was edited to actually answer the question posted so it also answers this question for people who are here specifically because they want the answer to *this* question.

Answer (score 176):

If you don't want to go with separate struct definition for nested struct and you don't like second method suggested by @OneOfOne you can use this third method:

```
package main
import "fmt"
type Configuration struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}

func main() {
    c := &Configuration{
        Val: "test",
    }

    c.Proxy.Address = `127.0.0.1`
    c.Proxy.Port = `8080`
}
```

You can check it here: https://play.golang.org/p/WoSYCxzCF2

Comment: Wow, an actual answer to the question of how to initialize **nested** structs.

Comment: This is actually pretty good, but would've been better if we could do it in one line!

Comment: I was looking for a way where you wouldn't need to do 

`c.Proxy.Address = \`127.0.0.1\``
`c.Proxy.Port = \`8080\``

Is there a way to initialize those values during `&Configuration{}` assignment?

Comment: @MatheusFelipe you can but then you have to define `Proxy` as its own struct, see first method in the answer by @OneOfOne

Comment: What when Proxy is an array, `Proxy []struct{}` ?

Comment: @Ishmeet both methods from the accepted answer work with slices.

Comment: @sepehr is there an example with slices ?

Comment: @Ishmeet [this is](https://go.dev/play/p/nMcDlUtBUmX) an example when Proxy is a slice.

Answer (score 17):

Define your `Proxy` struct separately, outside of `Configuration`, like this:

```
type Proxy struct {
    Address string
    Port    string
}

type Configuration struct {
    Val string
    P   Proxy
}

c := &Configuration{
    Val: "test",
    P: Proxy{
        Address: "addr",
        Port:    "80",
    },
}
```

See http://play.golang.org/p/7PELCVsQIc

Comment: What if `P   Proxy` is an array?

Answer (score 13):

You have this option also:

```
type Configuration struct {
        Val string
        Proxy
}

type Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
}

func main() {
        c := &Configuration{"test", Proxy{"addr", "port"}}
        fmt.Println(c)
}
```

Comment: Yes or the same with the second type of initializers [field:value](https://play.golang.org/p/tLmJKBEm-Vs)

Comment: What if `Proxy` is an array?

Comment: @ErtuğrulAltınboğa in this case you can do an `append(pxyArr, Proxy{"addr", "port"})`

Answer (score 11):

You also could allocate using `new` and initialize all fields by hand

```golang
package main

type Configuration struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}

func main() {
    c := new(Configuration)
    c.Val = "test"
    c.Proxy.Address = "addr"
    c.Proxy.Port = "80"
}
```

See in playground: https://play.golang.org/p/sFH_-HawO_M

Comment: Great example +1. For clarity you could add `fmt.Println(c.Val, c.Proxy.Address, c.Proxy.Port)`.

Comment: I'd like to add using `new()` only makes sense if you want a pointer. Otherwise just do `var c Configuration`.

Answer (score 9):

One gotcha arises when you want to instantiate a public type defined in an external package and that type embeds other types that are private.

Example:

```
package animals

type otherProps{
  Name string
  Width int
}

type Duck{
  Weight int
  otherProps
}
```

How do you instantiate a `Duck` in your own program? Here's the best I could come up with:

```
package main

import "github.com/someone/animals"

func main(){
  var duck animals.Duck
  // Can't instantiate a duck with something.Duck{Weight: 2, Name: "Henry"} because `Name` is part of the private type `otherProps`
  duck.Weight = 2
  duck.Width = 30
  duck.Name = "Henry"
}
```

Comment: For those how forgot like me, name your struct attributes with capital letters otherwise, you will face `cannot refer to unexported field or method ` error.

Answer (score 8):

You need to redefine the unnamed struct during `&Configuration{}`

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Configuration struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}

func main() {

    c := &Configuration{
        Val: "test",
        Proxy: struct {
            Address string
            Port    string
        }{
            Address: "127.0.0.1",
            Port:    "8080",
        },
    }
    fmt.Println(c)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Fv5QYylFGAY

Answer (score 2):

You can define a struct and create its object in another struct like i have done below:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Address struct {
    streetNumber int
    streetName   string
    zipCode      int
}

type Person struct {
    name    string
    age     int
    address Address
}

func main() {
    var p Person
    p.name = "Vipin"
    p.age = 30
    p.address = Address{
        streetName:   "Krishna Pura",
        streetNumber: 14,
        zipCode:      475110,
    }
    fmt.Println("Name: ", p.name)
    fmt.Println("Age: ", p.age)
    fmt.Println("StreetName: ", p.address.streetName)
    fmt.Println("StreeNumber: ", p.address.streetNumber)
}
```

Hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
package main

type    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }

type Configuration struct {
    Proxy
    Val   string

}

func main() {

    c := &Configuration{
        Val: "test",
        Proxy: Proxy {
            Address: "addr",
            Port:    "80",
        },
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your configuration is something global, you can do it this way:

```
package main

var Configuration struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}

func main() {
    Configuration.Val = "test"
    Configuration.Proxy.Address = "addr"
    Configuration.Proxy.Port = "80"
}
```