# Golang JSON for Struct - Error Message

Tags: json, struct, go

I am really new to Golang and I am trying to parse values to my ErrorMessage struct when an error occurs.

I have this struct:

```
type ErrorMessage struct {
    Errors []struct {
        Code    string `json:"code"`
        Message string `json:"message"`
        Field   string `json:"field,omitempty"`
    } `json:"errors"`
    Meta struct {
        Status string `json:"status"`
    } `json:"meta"`
}
```

Which is mapped to display JSON like this:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "short-code", 
            "message": "Wow, such bad!"
        },
        {
            "code": "other-code",
            "message": "OMG, very error!",
            "field": "This is the field"
        }
    ],
    "meta": {
        "status": "error"
    }
}
```

However I cannot work out how to parse the values from my controller into this Struct. For a basic Struct I understand and had something like this:
`e := models.ErrorMessage{"Error", "404", "Field Missing"}`

How would use a line similar to the above but for the more complicated Struct?

Comment: You want to create a value of `ErrorMessage` in Go, or you want to parse a JSON text into a variable of type `ErrorMessage`?

Comment: I want to create a value of ErrorMessage in Go which will basically then be rendered. `return c.RenderJson(e)`

Answer (score 0):

If you separate the `Error` and `Meta` from inline structs into pre-defined struct types, it becomes pretty straightforward:

```
type Error struct {
     Code    string `json:"code"`
     Message string `json:"message"`
     Field   string `json:"field,omitempty"`
}

type Meta struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

type ErrorMessage struct {
    Errors []Error `json:"errors"`
    Meta Meta `json:"meta"`
}

msg := ErrorMessage {
    Errors: []Error{
        {Code: "f00", Message: "bar", Field: "wat"},
    },
    Meta: Meta{"WAT"},
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you use anonymous structs as types of the fields of `ErrorMessage`. E.g. the element type of `ErrorMessage.Errors` is an anonymous struct. The type of `ErrorMessage.Meta` is also an anonymous struct.

Unfortunately initializing variables with anonymous struct types requires you to duplicate the anonymous struct declaration, see [this answer for examples and more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104985/1705598).

What I would suggest is to name your anonymous struct types like this:

```
type MyErr struct {
    Code    string `json:"code"`
    Message string `json:"message"`
    Field   string `json:"field,omitempty"`
}

type MyMeta struct {
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

type ErrorMessage struct {
    Errors []MyErr `json:"errors"`
    Meta   MyMeta  `json:"meta"`
}
```

And then your tasks becomes dead simple:

```
res := ErrorMessage{
    Errors: []MyErr{
        MyErr{
            Code:    "short-code",
            Message: "Wow, such bad!",
        },
        MyErr{
            Code:    "other-code",
            Message: "OMG, very error!",
            Field:   "This is the field",
        },
    },
    Meta: MyMeta{"error"},
}
data, err := json.MarshalIndent(&res, "", "  ")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

This will produce exactly your desired output. Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/o4PT-fYoOZ).