# How to initialize nested structure array in golang?

Tags: go

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809235/initialize-a-nested-struct-in-golang?rq=1), I'm try to initialize the following structure with some default values:

```
type Configuration struct {
    Val   string
    Proxy []struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without declaring `Proxy` separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can initialize it [as such](http://play.golang.org/p/yRiTVshL13)

```
cfg := Configuration{
    Val: "foo",
    Proxy: []struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }{
        {Address: "a", Port: "093"},
    },
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but since you have to declare the type somewhere, it gets (subjectively) ugly:

```
c := Configuration{
    Val: "value",
    Proxy: []struct {
        Address string
        Port    string
    }{
        {"addr1", "2"},
        {"addr2", "4"},
    },
}
```