# Refer to inner struct

Tags: go

I am trying to create some API docs programmatically, I have this:

```
type APIDoc struct {
    Route           string
    ResolutionValue struct {
       v           string
    }
}
```

and then I tried doing this:

```
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(APIDoc.ResolutionValue{"foo"})
```

but it says that

> APIDoc.ResolutionValue undefined (type APIDoc has no method
>   ResolutionValue)

so I resorted to doing this:

```
type ResolutionValue struct {
    v string
}

type APIDoc struct {
    Route           string
    ResolutionValue ResolutionValue
}
```

and then doing:

```
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(ResolutionValue{"foo"})
```

kinda lame tho, is there a way to ensure integrity somehow?

Comment: Are you trying to implement an inner type? If so, that is really hard to do without making it messy. I'd suggest going with your second option.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809235/initialize-a-nested-struct-in-golang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Go 1.11, nested types are not supported.

[Proposal discussion](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20467)

Your revision looks a lot nicer IMO.

Edit: Maybe unrelated to the question but you can use type embedding to simplify your types. However, note that the representation are different:

```
type Inner struct {
    Whatever int
}

type ResolutionValue struct {
    Val string
    Inner
}

type ResolutionValue2 struct {
    Val    string
    Inner Inner
}

func main() {

    a, _ := json.Marshal(ResolutionValue{})
    b, _ := json.Marshal(ResolutionValue2{})
    fmt.Printf("%s\n%s", a, b)

}
```

Which prints:

```
{"Val":"","Whatever":0}
{"Val":"","Inner":{"Whatever":0}}
```

Comment: yeah you may want to mention that I can just do `ResolutionValue` instead of `ResolutionValue ResolutionValue`, I just learned that a few minutes ago

Comment: For example, `Inner` here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53039039/creating-json-from-struct-not-struct-value

Comment: I'd edit the answer, but based from what you were trying to accomplish, it was more of an inner struct/type.