# Creating JSON from struct, not struct value

Tags: json, go

I imagine I would need the reflect package to do this. Say I have a struct like so:

```
type Inner struct {
   Whatever int
}

type ResolutionValue struct {
    Val string
    Inner
}
```

say I want to generate a JSON representation of the ResolutionValue struct...is there some way to create a JSON representation without instantiating it?

Comment: What's wrong with fmt.Sprintf("{}")?

Comment: @Volker maybe you can write what you think the question means? How would I get the struct  representation into there? aka,`fmt.Sprintf(ResolutionValue)`

Comment: What is the JSON encoding of a non-existing i.e. non-instantiated thing? It probably is a fixed string. So just use that string value. If it is something dynamic it probably depends on the values. If you are interested in the struct fields: Reflect. The requirement "not instantiated" is 100% useless as it unnecessarily complicates things without any benefit. Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with reflection, you would need an actual value to get the type using `reflect.TypeOf`. So I would suggest just using the zero value of your type.

```
json.Marshal(ResolutionValue{})
```