# How to initialize []struct

Tags: go

I have generated go struct from json.
And it gave me next output:

```
type PartnerBody87 struct {
    Imp []struct {
        Bidfloor float64 `json:"bidfloor"`
        Secure   int     `json:"secure"`
        Ext      struct {
            Type    string `json:"type"`
            Webpush int    `json:"webpush"`
        } `json:"ext"`
        ID    string `json:"id"`
        Tagid string `json:"tagid"`
    } `json:"imp"`
}
```

I tried different ways, and cannot find proper one of how to initiate the value for
Imp []struct.

Update:
I know that I can split struct into few types. But I'm curious if Go have ability to set everything in 1 struct - than how to use it?

Comment: @blackgreen hm... So according to this post. In Go i have ability to set such anonymous struct type, but to use it I have to redefine it again... Than what is the purpose of that feature...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to initialize a nested struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809235/how-to-initialize-a-nested-struct)

Comment: *i have ability to set such anonymous struct type, but to use it I have to redefine it again* — correct; *Than what is the purpose of that feature* — I find it mostly useful for json **de**serialization

Comment: @blackgreen oh... that's strange. But any way thanks!

Comment: This can help? https://go.dev/play/p/flImqkSm-3c

Comment: @MarioSantini yeah - blackgreen already mentioned that. But thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can split them like this:

```golang
type PartnerBody87 struct {
    Imp []Imp `json:"imp"`
}

type Imp struct {
    Bidfloor float64 `json:"bidfloor"`
    Secure   int     `json:"secure"`
    Ext      Ext     `json:"ext"`
    ID       string  `json:"id"`
    Tagid    string  `json:"tagid"`
}
type Ext struct {
    Type    string `json:"type"`
    Webpush int    `json:"webpush"`
}
```

Comment: Yes - but I'm making code generation solution, so this doesn't fully working for me.